# how to login using Facebook or twitter in rails and i get an error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have followed the tutorial from http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1 and http://railscasts.com/episodes/236-omniauth-part-2 and I am getting an error

```
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]
```

what should i do?

Update:
error

```
 app/models/user.rb:9:in `apply_omniauth'
 app/controllers/authentications_controller.rb:18:in `create'
```

Comment: You should give more details... When is this message shown ? what is around the message (a stacktrace, a line number when the error occured) ?

Comment: Paste the backtrace of the error